# Optimising Java Scanner to match regex in file faster

Tags: java, regex

I am currently using this code to match a regex against a lot of files, however, this is fairly slow. Is there a way I can do the same thing, but faster?

```
public class Filter {
    private String title;
    private String regex;
    private List<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();
    ...
}
```

I have a few Filters for different types of regexes, they range from matching emails to matching words like apikey, ... The code will be used to scan for vulnerabilities in decompiled classes and other text based files.

My code also only checks for 1 match in a file, I'd like to get all matches.

```
public void startScans() {
    List<File> files = getAllFiles(getFolder()); //Gets a list of all text based files in a folder
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        for(Filter filter : getFilters()) {
            try {
                System.out.print("\rScanning file " + i + " out of " + files.size() + " using filter " + filter.getTitle() + "...");
                scanFile(files.get(i), filter);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ignored) {}
        }
    }
}

private void scanFile(File f, Filter filter) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    String result = scanner.findWithinHorizon(filter.getRegex(), 0);
    if (result != null) {
        filter.addResult(result);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Is `regex` a `String` or `Pattern`? Is it the same among different runs?

Comment: First of all we need to establish which bit is slow: is it the file reading or the regex matching?

Comment: Post more code, this is not enough to determine what you're trying to do and why what you're doing is slow

Comment: Added more code now.

Comment: Regex on stream is slow, since it will try to match, then check hit end to deduce if more input can change the result, then match again. Since you set horizon parameter to 0, if your regex is permissive, it's possible that Scanner has to read the whole file into memory before it can determine whether there is a match or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an external tool if you want a faster execution, that is, execute a command. e.g.

- Windows: `findstr /R [a-z]*xyz *`
- Linux: `egrep -R "[a-z]*xyz" .`

<sub>**NOTE**: You can run these commands from Java.</sub>

Comment: I could try that but I want it to work on as much systems as possible. I also use the matches I get to generate a html report, so executing a external command and then getting the output from it seems quite hacky. I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to do this in java.

Comment: *Yup*. It is necessary to clean the output of these commands.